# How can get all processes beginning with specified character in windows?

Tags: windows, process

`tasklist` can list all processes running in windows.How can get all running processes beginning with specified character (for example ,beginning with `c` ) in windows?

Comment: export to a list an sort it

Comment: maybe you can use `find`: `tasklist | find "chrome.exe"`

Comment: @MarkusMeyer, as in my answer below, `findstr` is the right one to use, since `find` cannot search specifically for the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`findstr` is what you need, you can pipe the output of `tasklist` to `findstr` and have it output only the lines starting with a c.

So to get all process starting with a ***c*** you will use:

```
tasklist | findstr /B /I c
```

Explanation:

- `tasklist` lists all currently running processes
- `|` pipes all output of the previous command into the next
- `findstr` searches in the output for
- `/B` *Matches pattern if at the beginning of a line*
- `/I` *Specifies that the search is not to be case-sensitive*, so it will find *cmd.exe* and also *Chrome.exe*
- `c` is the character we're looking for

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Powershell:

```
Get-Process -Name "c*"
```

The cmdlet will return the processes whose name start with `c`.